# Customizing table of contents in memoir

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

I have a table of contents in my `memoir` document, but I want to slightly alter the way it appears:

1) I want to decrease the spacing between chapters (now it looks double-spaced; I want something like 1.3 spacing).

2) I don't want the names of chapters to appear in bold (I still want the chapter numbers to be bold, just not the chapter names).

Which settings can customize these options?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can redefine `\cftchapteraftersnumb` and  `\cftbeforechapterskip`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnumb{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapterskip{5pt plus 1pt}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]