# How to unbold abstract and others titles

Tags: document-classes, bold, abnt

I'm using a Brazilian template to write my final project in college. Everything is ok, but I need to unbold some titles, like abstract, resumo (it's a abstract in Portuguese), list of figures and tables, agradecimentos (acknowledgement in Portuguese) and list of symbols. All those titles need to be in caps and normal font. Here is a Simplified code that I 'm using and need to change.

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    twoside,            % para impressão em recto e verso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,     % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,     % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,  % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    french,             % idioma adicional para hifenização
    spanish,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,             % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}


% ---
% PACOTES
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes fundamentais 
% ---
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados no anexo do modelo de folha de identificação
% ---
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text
% ---

% ---
% Pacotes de citações
% ---
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT

% --- 
% CONFIGURAÇÕES DE PACOTES
% --- 

% ---
% Configurações do pacote backref
% Usado sem a opção hyperpageref de backref
\renewcommand{\backrefpagesname}{Citado na(s) página(s):~}
% Texto padrão antes do número das páginas
\renewcommand{\backref}{}
% Define os textos da citação
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        Nenhuma citação no texto.%
    \or
        Citado na página #2.%
    \else
        Citado #1 vezes nas páginas #2.%
    \fi}%
% ---

% ---
% Informações de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO
% ---
\titulo{Modelo Canônico de\\ Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico com \abnTeX}
\autor{Equipe \abnTeX}
\local{Brasil}
\data{2015, v-1.9.6}
\instituicao{%
  Universidade do Brasil -- UBr
  \par
  Faculdade de Arquitetura da Informação
  \par
  Programa de Pós-Graduação}
\tipotrabalho{Relatório técnico}
% O preambulo deve conter o tipo do trabalho, o objetivo, 
% o nome da instituição e a área de concentração 
\preambulo{Modelo canônico de Relatório Técnico e/ou Científico em conformidade
com as normas ABNT apresentado à comunidade de usuários \LaTeX.}
% ---

% ---
% Configurações de aparência do PDF final

% alterando o aspecto da cor azul
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{41,5,195}

% informações do PDF
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
        %pagebackref=true,
        pdftitle={\@title}, 
        pdfauthor={\@author},
        pdfsubject={\imprimirpreambulo},
        pdfcreator={LaTeX with abnTeX2},
        pdfkeywords={abnt}{latex}{abntex}{abntex2}{relatório técnico}, 
        colorlinks=true,            % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=blue,             % color of internal links
        citecolor=blue,             % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta,              % color of file links
        urlcolor=blue,
        bookmarksdepth=4
}
\makeatother
% --- 

% --- 
% Espaçamentos entre linhas e parágrafos 
% --- 

% O tamanho do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% ---
% compila o indice
% ---
\makeindex
% ---

% ----
% Início do documento
% ----
\begin{document}

% Seleciona o idioma do documento (conforme pacotes do babel)
%\selectlanguage{english}
\selectlanguage{brazil}

% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 


% ---
% Agradecimentos
% ---
\begin{agradecimentos}
O agradecimento principal é direcionado a Youssef Cherem, autor do
\nameref{formulado-identificacao} (\autopageref{formulado-identificacao}).

Os agradecimentos especiais são direcionados ao Centro de Pesquisa em
Arquitetura da Informação\footnote{\url{http://www.cpai.unb.br/}} da Universidade de
Brasília (CPAI), ao grupo de usuários
\emph{latex-br}\footnote{\url{http://groups.google.com/group/latex-br}} e aos
novos voluntários do grupo
\emph{\abnTeX}\footnote{\url{http://groups.google.com/group/abntex2} e
\url{http://www.abntex.net.br/}}~que contribuíram e que ainda
contribuirão para a evolução do abn\TeX.

\end{agradecimentos}
% ---

% ---
% RESUMO
% ---

% resumo na língua vernácula (obrigatório)
\setlength{\absparsep}{18pt} % ajusta o espaçamento dos parágrafos do resumo
\begin{resumo}
 Segundo a \citeonline[3.1-3.2]{NBR6028:2003}, o resumo deve ressaltar o
 objetivo, o método, os resultados e as conclusões do documento. A ordem e a extensão
 destes itens dependem do tipo de resumo (informativo ou indicativo) e do
 tratamento que cada item recebe no documento original. O resumo deve ser
 precedido da referência do documento, com exceção do resumo inserido no
 próprio documento. (\ldots) As palavras-chave devem figurar logo abaixo do
 resumo, antecedidas da expressão Palavras-chave:, separadas entre si por
 ponto e finalizadas também por ponto.

     \noindent
     \textbf{Palavras-chaves}: latex. abntex. editoração de texto.
    \end{resumo}
    % ---
    \begin{resumo}[Abstract]
     \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}


       \vspace{\onelineskip}

       \noindent 
       \textbf{Keywords}: keywords.
     \end{otherlanguage*}
    \end{resumo}
    % ---
    % inserir lista de ilustrações
    % ---
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures*
    \cleardoublepage
    % ---

    % ---
    % inserir lista de tabelas
    % ---
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
    \listoftables*
    \cleardoublepage
    % ---

    % ---
    % inserir lista de abreviaturas e siglas
    % ---
    \begin{siglas}
      \item[ABNT] Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas
      \item[abnTeX] ABsurdas Normas para TeX
    \end{siglas}
    % ---

    % ---
    % inserir lista de símbolos
    % ---
    \begin{simbolos}
      \item[$ \Gamma $] Letra grega Gama
      \item[$ \Lambda $] Lambda
      \item[$ \zeta $] Letra grega minúscula zeta
      \item[$ \in $] Pertence
    \end{simbolos}

% ---

% ---
%% inserir o sumario
%% ---
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
%\tableofcontents*
%\cleardoublepage
%% ---


% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\textual

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm brazilian as well and used `abntex2` for my term paper. As far as I know those titles are formatted according to `\ABNTEXchapterfont`. So if you change that to say `\normalfont` would solve the issue, although all chapters will change as well, is that ok or it _has_ to be just the ones you described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `abntex2` class has its chapters and sections formatted according to commands like `\ABNTEXsectionfont` and `\ABNTEXsectionfontsize`. So you only need to renew those commands, to get the chapters back on bold face (if needed) just renew the command again like the MWE below. Note the `chapter=TITLE` as class option, that makes the chapters and therefore Resumo, Agradecimentos, etc uppercase (it's all the in [`abntex` manual](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2.pdf) -in pt_BR- you can also check out the `.cls` file to see how things work, it is not that complicated!)

```
\documentclass[chapter = TITLE]{abntex2}

\title{The title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\normalfont} %Here you change the font to normal (Roman in this case)

\begin{document}
\imprimircapa

\begin{resumo}
Here goes the ``resumo''
\end{resumo}

\textual
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\bfseries} % And here you get it to boldface
\chapter{The first chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I didn't knew the command `{\ABNTEXchapterfont}`. You seved my life. Thanks again.

Comment: There are one of those for each level. Take a look at the manual (it's very short), if you get in trouble with the ToC the solution lies within [Customizing table of contents in memoir](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50879/customizing-table-of-contents-in-memoir) - that one gave me a headache! Good luck with your paper.

Comment: @TúlioAlves, just check the documentation -- the answer to your question was already there.